# cakephp find all and afterFind method

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, belongs-to, findall

I have a model that has a belongsTo variable, find and a afterFind all in play. The problem is, when the afterFind is commented out find works fine, but once its in play the find only returns "true", not an array of objects. If anyone has ran into this issue please inform me thx!

Model:

```
     public $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            ),
            'ContactCategory' => array(
                'className' => 'ContactCategory',
                'foreignKey' => 'contact_category_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            ),
            'State' => array(
                'className' => 'State',
                'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
            )
        );

        public function getContact($id)
        {
            if ($id) {
                $contact = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Contact.id' => $id), 'fields' => array('id', 'image')));
                return $contact;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function afterFind($results = array(), $primary = false)
        {
            foreach ($results as $key => &$val) {
                if (isset($val['Contact'])) {
                    $this->decryptFields($val['Contact'], $this->fieldsToEncrypt());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It returns true because your afterFind function runs without any issue, you should put a return statement in the afterFind function with the array that you want

Comment: Yeah returning the results seems to work now. Thx, wonder why this needs to be done on this model only. cool.